# Avoiding null indexes in my array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to write a new document based on the Objects I have in my side2[] array. 
Now unfortunately, some indexes are null in this array, and when it hits one of them, it just gives me a NullPointerException. This array has 10 indexes, but in this case not all of them are needed. I have tried the try catch statement in hopes of continuing after it comes across a null, but it still stops execution and doesn't write a new document.
The stack (srail) that is part of the object contains the data I want to print out.

Here is my code:

```
    // Write to the file
    for(int y=0; y<=side2.length; y++)
    { 
        String g = side2[y].toString();

        if(side2[y]!=null){
            while(!side2[y].sRail.isEmpty())
            {
                out.write(side2[y].sRail.pop().toString());
                out.newLine();
                out.newLine();
            }
            out.write(g);
        }
    }

    //Close the output stream/file
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the code calls `toString()` on the `side2[y]` object *before* checking it for `null`. You can skip `null` objects by adding a condition at the top of the loop, like this:

```
for(int y=0; y<=side2.length; y++) {
    if(side2[y] == null) {
        continue;
    }
    String g = side2[y].toString();
    // No further checks for null are necessary on side2[y]
    while(!side2[y].sRail.isEmpty()) {
        out.write(side2[y].sRail.pop().toString());
        out.newLine();
        out.newLine();
    }
    out.write(g);
}
```